# Doesn't work EventListener in a-frame 0.8.2

Tags: javascript, aframe

This code works properly in A-frame 0.8.0.
But I cannot get camera rotation from EventListner in A-frame 0.8.2.
Does anybody have solution?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-box color="tomato" position="0 0 -5"depth="2" height="4" width="0.5"></a-box>
        <a-camera id="camera" ></a-camera>
    </a-scene>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        var target = document.querySelector('[camera]');
        target.addEventListener('componentchanged', function(event) {
            console.log(target.getAttribute('rotation'));
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you won't grab `<a-camera>` with the `[camera]` css selector. Instead you should use `document.querySelector(a-camera)`.

2) It's better to poll the rotation value in a custom component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  tick: function() {
    console.log(this.el.getAttribute("rotation")
  }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<a-camera foo></a-camera>
```

Check it out in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5utxh12/5/)

Comment: I see.
Thank you so much!

Comment: @Kiyu if you don't have further questions feel free to mark the anwser